# Java For Loop as an argument

Tags: java, arrays, function, for-loop, try-catch

I have been trying to make this for loop

```
    for ( int  i = 0; i < Main.ipList.length; i++){
        JButton btn = new JButton();
        btn.setText(Main.ipList[i]);

        panel.add(btn);
        btn.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
                Main.refreshSpecificIp(i);
                System.out.println("Bu");
            }   
        });
    }
```

`Main.refreshSpecificIp(i)` is giving me an error saying 'i' has to be final or effectivly final. Here is the refreshSpecificIp function:

```
 public static void refreshSpecificIp(Integer d){
        try
        {
            InetAddress inet = InetAddress.getByName(ipList[d]);
            System.out.println("Sending Ping Request to " + ipList[d]);

            boolean status = inet.isReachable(500000); //Timeout = 5000 milli seconds

            if (status)
            {
                System.out.println("Status : " + ipList[d]+ " Host is reachable");
            }
            else
            {
                System.out.println("Status " + ipList[d]+ " Host is not reachable");
            }
        }
        catch (UnknownHostException e)
        {
            System.err.println(ipList[d] + " Host does not exists");
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            System.err.println(ipList[d] + " Error in reaching the Host");
        }
    }
    static String[] ipList = {"127.0.0.1", "173.57.51.111", "69.696.69.69"};
```

If you can please help me so I can continue with my project.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define another local variable, declare it as final, and assign the value of `i` to it:

```
for ( int  i = 0; i < Main.ipList.length; i++){
    JButton btn = new JButton();
    btn.setText(Main.ipList[i]);
    panel.add(btn);
    final int j = i;
    btn.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
            Main.refreshSpecificIp(j);
            System.out.println("Bu");
        }   
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks man, I had a brain fart and didn't think of it that way! You are aweseome!

Answer (score 1):

`i` has to be `final` because anonymous inner class can't use outer variable unless it's `final`.

The only case where it can be used without `final` is  if it is passed directly to the constructor of the class being subclassed by anonymous class.